# add_star function not adding attributes in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

For some reason add_star() is not inputting the attributes to the nodes.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
nx.add_star(G, [0,1,2], weight=1)

>>>G.nodes.data()
NodeDataView({0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}})

>>>G.node[0]
{}
```

Any idea what's going on??

Versions:
Python 2.7
Networkx 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *attributes* you mean the edge weights, the weights are added as edge attributes:

```
G = nx.Graph()
nx.add_star(G, [0,1,2], weight=1)
G.edges(data=True)
# EdgeDataView([(0, 1, {'weight': 1}), (0, 2, {'weight': 1})])
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I thought by attributes they were talking about node attributes.